# errors running swt java application

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, swt

I use debian 9 gnu linux.When i run the application with eclipse i got these errors:
Shell cannot be resolved to a type
Display cannot be resolved to a type
The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved

I installed swt from help> install new software

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class SWTapplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();

    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    // the layout manager handle the layout
    // of the widgets in the container
    //shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    //TODO add some widgets to the Shell
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
}
```

Comment: Using "help > install new software" is not adding SWT as a dependency to your project. Are you using Maven, or Gradle, or some other tool?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather compiler than runtime error. To fix this you need to add SWT Java library as a build dependency to your project.
Go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path and click "Add External JARs..." button (on the right hand side).
Enter /usr/share/java/swt.jar as a location there and click "OK".
Project should now build without errors and open empty window.

Comment: thanks this is works!but i have new problem.I'll open new question.

Comment: @Andrea Remember to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved the issue described in the question.